# How to Classify Texts using a Multi-label classifier in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning

My problem is that, it outputs  "UserWarning: Label not 0 is present in all training examples." I cannot understand what it means, and it is my first time to do a machine learning code. Please help me graduate and learn, thank you.

```
            dataFrame = [] #list of data
            categories = ['python', 'if-statement', 'for-loop', 'java']
            for i in range(len(data["items"])):

                #Convert html code to text since data["items"][i]["body"] returns something like this: "<p>I have 2 columns <p>""
                html_to_text = h.handle(data["items"][i]["body"])
                html_to_text = html_to_text.lower()

                #converts "what's" to "what is", removes \t, and so on...
                clean_text = preprocess_text(html_to_text)

                data_dict = {'question_body' : clean_text, 'python' : [0], 'if-statement': [0], 'for-loop': [0], 'java' : [0]}

                #change the label to 1 if it is a label of the question
                for j in range(len(data["items"][i]["tags"])):
                    if data["items"][i]["tags"][j] in categories:
                        current_key_index = data["items"][i]["tags"][j]
                        data_dict[current_key_index] = 1

                #convert to data frame using Pandas     
                from_data_dict =  pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_dict)
                dataFrame.append(from_data_dict)

            #train and test data split from scikit
            train, test = train_test_split(dataFrame, test_size=0.33, shuffle=True)
            #print(train)

            X_train = []
            X_test = []
            for i in range(len(train)):
                X_train.append(train[i].question_body)
            # print(X_train[0])

            for j in range(len(test)):
                X_test.append(test[j].question_body)

            SVC_pipeline = Pipeline([
                            ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=stop_words)),
                            ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC(), n_jobs=1)),
                        ])
            for category in categories:
                print('... Processing {}'.format(category))

                # train the model using X_dtm & y
                for i in range(len(X_train)):
                    SVC_pipeline.fit(X_train[i], train[i][category])
```

I'm focusing on creating the model first before predicting so the code ends here.

Answer (score 2):

The error message states that all the samples in the training set have 0 label when used in train_test_split function. 
As debug I suggest to print  train[i][category] to be sure that there are at least some 1s in the training set.

As general suggestion: use "stratify= True" in the train_test_split. This will force the splitting to have some samples from both classes.

If you have only zeros in the labels probably you should double check that the "current_key_index " is indeed a key of your dictionary. If none of your labels switch to one, probably is due to a failure in: data_dict[current_key_index] = 1

Finally would be cleaner to have the sample and the label linked in the same data structure (e.g. tuple [sample, label]) rather than two independent structure as in: SVC_pipeline.fit(X_train[i], train[i][category]). This would minimize the error due to mismatched indexing.